# Unable to download, install Mongodb 3.2 on Fedora 23

Tags: mongodb, installation, fedora

O.S. - Fedora 23 64 bit
Followed procedure given on
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/

1. Created the `yum.repos.d/mongodb.repo` file
2. `sudo yum install -y mongodb-org`

   Throws an error

   ```
    No such package - mongodb-org
   ```

Followed the steps - http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-mongodb-on-fedora-20/

1. Created the repo file with given URL
2. Installed the mongo

Result - mongo version 2.6.12
And not the latest release

Answer (score 0):

The path is `/etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb.repo`, instead of `yum.repos.d/mongodb.repo`. You also need to fill the file with the content

```
[mongodb-org-3.2]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/7/mongodb-org/3.2/x86_64/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-3.2.asc
```

Comment: This is exactly what I did                                                                       vim /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb.repo
[root@chai /]# sudo yum install -y mongodb-org

Repository mongodb-org-3.2 is listed more than once in the configuration
Last metadata expiration check: 2:53:29 ago on Thu Jun 30 16:27:31 2016.
No package mongodb-org available.
Error: Unable to find a match.

Comment: Let's try to replace `$releasever` with `7` (install rhel7 version) in the file as above. It should do the job. There is no release for Fedora if I see right.

Comment: Tried replacing, still no package mongodb-org available